# Managing multiple Event listeners for same node in Firebase database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Facing some problem in Firebase android, suppose I have two database reference for fetching one node data in multiple places in app, and turned on Event listener for every reference, So if any changes happen, will all database reference be invoked?

If yes, then is there any way to invoke one at a time, even event listener is on for multiple database reference for same Node

Comment: That depends on the database structure and the code, neither of which you shared. For getting the best help, edit your question to include a [minimal reproduction (code+JSON, all as text) of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (I recommend studying the link, it's quite useful).

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple references all pointing to the exact same location in the database, and you have listeners on all those references, then any change to the data at that location will trigger *all* of the listeners.

If you don't want a listener to trigger on a change, remove it from the reference where you added it.  There is no other way to conditionally indicate that a listener should be triggered based on some other condition - you just add and remove them.

Comment: Thanks Doug for your answer. I changed my firebase Crud operation structrue. now problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

After @DougStevens tip and my effort, I solved this problem by changing the way of calling Firebase API.. Actually, was calling firebase APIs in wrong way..

Comment: It will be good if you can share some relevant code for how you resolve it. It will help other developers. Happy coding.